# Take Speech Recognition Transcript And Insert Into HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use speech recognition to fill a `<p>` element with react. I'm not sure how to put the transcript into the `<p>` tag

Here is what I have so far:

```js
import React from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition'

const Dictaphone = () => {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition()

    if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
            <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
            <p>{transcript}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Dictaphone
```

Comment: By text field you mean the paragraph tags? Rather than an input tag with the text type?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the value of the `textarea` equal to `{newItem}` rather than `{transcript}`. Unless you are doing something behind the scenes (like setting the value of `newItem` equal to `transcript`) then this should work:

```
<textarea className='text-area'
  placeholder='Write something you would like to remember one day. 500 character limit.' 
  type='text'
  id='foo'
  maxLength='500'
  value={transcript}
  onChange={e => { setAllowSubmit(true); setNewItem(e.target.value); }}
/>
```

Also, what is the onChange listener supposed to actually do?

Comment: @Brandon no problem - let me know if it helps